# strange behavior of logger

Tags: python, logging, gunicorn

I encountered such a problem and couldn't solve it. I used python's logger to log info, logger level set to logging.DEBUG. I used gunicorn to log
info at the same time. Normally, the error message goes to python's logger, and the link messages and other messages written by logger.info or logger.debug goes to the log file of gunicorn. However with one application it doesn't behave so. The messages output by logger.info also goes to python's logger. The problem is, I only want to see error messages in python's logger, all the other messages would be seen from gunicorn's logger. Can anyone give me a clue where I might do wrong in this situation?

thx in advance,
alex

The following is my config:

```
LOGGER_LEVEL = logging.DEBUG  
LOGGER_ROOT_NAME = "root"  
LOGGER_ROOT_HANLDERS = [logging.StreamHandler, logging.FileHandler]  
LOGGER_ROOT_LEVEL = LOGGER_LEVEL  
LOGGER_ROOT_FORMAT = "[%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s"  
LOGGER_LEVEL = logging.ERROR  
LOGGER_FILE_PATH = "/data/log/web/"
```

Code:

```
def config_root_logger(self):
    formatter = logging.Formatter(self.config.LOGGER_ROOT_FORMAT)

    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(self.config.LOGGER_ROOT_LEVEL)

    filename = os.path.join(self.config.LOGGER_FILE_PATH, "secondordersrv.log")
    handler = logging.FileHandler(filename)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    # 测试环境配置再增加console的日志记录
    self._add_test_handler(logger, formatter)

def _add_test_handler(self, logger, formatter):
    # 测试环境配置再增加console的日志记录
    if self.config.RUN_MODE == 'test':
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
```

My gunicorn config looks like this:

```
errorlog = '/data/log/web/%s.log' % APP_NAME  
loglevel = 'info'  
accesslog = '-'
```

Comment: Sounds like a issue with the logging configuration.  It would help if you provide the logging related code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not set the level of your handler.

After `handler.setFormatter(formatter)`, add the following line:

```
handler.setLevel(self.config.LOGGER_LEVEL)
```

Comment: Actually you are right. However I wrote another application using the same config, but it works without adding this setting-level. I feel very strange. BTW, how did you change my input style? I added 4 spaces before my code but it just didn't show right.

Comment: With regards to input style, you need an empty line between the text and the first line of code.